# mongoose - setter not called on sub(-sub) document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema structure:

```
var ProgramSchema = new Schema({
 ...
 networks: [NetworksSchema]
});

  var NetworksSchema = new Schema({
    payments: [NetworkPaymentsSchema],
    ...
  });

    var NetworkPaymentsSchema = new Schema({
      ...
      amount: { type: Number, get: genFunc.getCurrency, set: genFunc.setCurrency, required: true }
    });
```

Whenever I create() or save() a ProgramSchema, the getter and setter in NetworkPaymentsSchema are not called.

So far I tried to call the setter this way:

```
NetworkPaymentsSchema.path('amount').set(genFunc.setCurrency);
```

Doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Please note that variable definition order matters in JavaScript. Upon running your snippet ProgramSchema will look like this:

```
var ProgramSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  networks: [undefined] // Which is effectively equivalent to mongoose.SchemaTypes.Mixed or {}
});
```

This happens because at the moment of definition of ProgramSchema neither NetworkSchema nor NetworkPaymentSchema is defined. Though they are both declared due to [hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp), which prevents program from crashing with ReferenceError. Thus there is no any relation between your schemas.

So to fix your problem you must move definitions of sub-schemas above the ProgramSchema's one. I.e. your code must look like the following (notice the order of schemas definition):

```
var NetworkPaymentsSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  amount: { type: Number, get: genFunc.getCurrency, set: genFunc.setCurrency, required: true }
});

var NetworksSchema = new Schema({
  payments: [NetworkPaymentsSchema],
  ...
});

var ProgramSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  networks: [NetworksSchema]
});
```

I have tested on MongoDB 2.6.4 and Mongoose 3.8.17 and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following before which worked for me. I assume you are saving prices in cents instead of a float. You shouldn't have to call the setter, mongoose should do that for you. Just save the data.

```
Schema: {
  amount: {type: Number, get: getPrice, set: setPrice }
}

function getPrice(num){
  return Number((num/100).toFixed(2));
}

function setPrice(num){
  return Number(num)*100;
}
```